# Remove Physical Volume from Volume Group

Tags: lvm

How do you remove a PV from a VG?

Here's what I've tried:

```
# vgreduce vg_iscsi /dev/sdb1
Physical volume "/dev/sdb1" still in use

# lvs
LV         VG       Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  root       centos   -wi-ao----   6.67g                                                    
  swap       centos   -wi-ao---- 820.00m                                                    
  lvm02      vg2      -wi-a----- 800.00m                                                    
  lv_iscsi_1 vg_iscsi -wi-ao----  52.00m
```

Then

```
# lvremove -f vg_iscsi/lv_iscsi_1
Logical volume vg_iscsi/lv_iscsi_1 in use.
```

Using `fuser`

```
# fuser -kuc /dev/vg_iscsi/lv_iscsi_1
/dev/dm-3:            1558(root)
```

I tried to `kill -9` this but the process seemed to have disappeared by the time I issued the `kill` signal.

However, now I get this:

```
# vgreduce vg_iscsi /dev/sdb1
Can't remove final physical volume "/dev/sdb1" from volume group "vg_iscsi"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/removepvsfromvg.html

Comment: please include more details, as it's nearly impossible to help with amount of details that you provide

Comment: Are you trying to delete your data?

Comment: @MichaelHampton just a test system. Want to remove the PV

Comment: OK, since you don't want to delete your data, then you need to move your data to another PV. That being so, it's not clear why you're trying to run `lvremove` at all. That _is_ destructive and _will_ delete your data.

Comment: Wasn't being clear - yes, completely happy to lose the data. It's just a test system.

Answer (score 8):

The `vgreduce` command is correct, but you can't remove a physical volume from the volume group until it's empty. That is what the error message that you received means.

As the man page states:

```
       To move all Physical Extents that are used by simple Logical Volumes on
       /dev/sdb1 to free Physical Extents elsewhere in the Volume Group use:

       pvmove /dev/sdb1
```

Once the PV is empty, you can then repeat the `vgreduce` command to remove it.

Comment: When I run `pvmove /dev/nvme1n1` I get `No extents available for allocation.` – What does this mean?

Answer (score 2):

per `man lvremove` to remove, you should run

> lvremove -f vg00/lvol1

please me mindful that parameter will be different in your case.

Comment: I got an `in use` message. See my Q.

Comment: If you want to remove the logical volume, unmount it first. It's in use because it's mounted.